# How do i set basic authentication using apache httpClient

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-commons-httpclient

I am trying to do a `PATCH` request using `Apache` `httpclient` and I am unsure how to set basic authentication. This is how im currently trying to do it. I know that my auth params are correct and i can authenticate using GET ... but for GET im currently using httpURLConnection rather than Apache httpClient .

With this code I am getting back a 403 response and I believe its because im not setting the auth info correctly. I know that i just need to do basic authentication and feed it X_AUTH_USER, X_AUTH_CRED.

```
Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(X_AUTH_USER, X_AUTH_CRED.toCharArray());
        }
    });

    HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    HttpPatch patch = new HttpPatch(buildUrl());


    try {
        StringEntity input = new StringEntity(buildJson(jsonList));
        input.setContentType("application/json");
        patch.setEntity(input);

        System.out.println(patch);

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(patch);

        System.out.print(response.getStatusLine());
        for(Header header : response.getAllHeaders()){
            System.out.println(header.getName() + " : " + header.getValue());
        }
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: There are various code samples for Apache HttpClient in their [example page](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/examples.html).

Comment: added current code block that returns 403

Comment: can you provide more code. how do you set other header properties as Access-Control-Allow-Methods. this may help: http://crunchify.com/what-is-cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-how-to-add-it-to-your-java-jersey-web-server/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

```
Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication("UserName", "P@sw0rd".toCharArray());
    }
});
```

You also need to set other header properties: (example)

```
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://podcastpedia.org");
//allows CORS requests only coming from podcastpedia.org
```

**Code to add a basic authentication property to an httpURLConnection**

```
String basic = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(("admin:1234").getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);

con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", basic);
```

Comment: looking for how to do it in httpClient not httpURLConnection

Comment: sry just saw and start writing :) I updated it. tell me if it works.

Comment: I believe that. you can set it one time when you start your application. but, It only needed before the first http request. is that an android app?

Comment: no not android ... using java to connect to a rest interface

Comment: put it before you initialise your http client.

Comment: Still getting 403 ... but im seeing this in the response headers ... it looks to me like it doesnt like that im doing a patch 

Access-Control-Allow-Methods : POST,GET,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE

Comment: Are you sure that the implementation with httpURLConnection work? did you test it for the same service?

Comment: httpURLConnection worked for GET ... but it doesnt support PATCH

Comment: then, to make sure why don't you use this code for authentication I provided for GET. then we can tell where to go from there?